# transfer wordpress from localhost to an other no access to phpmyadmin

Tags: wordpress, localhost, transfer

thanks for your time,

i've been working on my website with wordpress, on localhost (Xamp), but i had some difficulties with my hard drive who seems to have a lot of bad sectors until it stopped booting or anything, i have managed to get my data out but i have no idea how to set up my website on the new OS new Hdd, well the same old website, i have the whole xamp folder i have the htdocs/mywebsite folder too, can anyone help.  cant extract the database from phpmyadmin cause the computer wont boot with the old drive.
hope i was clear, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Install xampp on another machine, put your project folder in htdocs folder of new xampp installation and then edit the config.php in your project folder to reflect your new env values ( which are your db name, password etc)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this below process

"Copy your project folder from backup xampp folder and past in your new xampp"

C:\xampp\htdocs

"Copy your database in folder from backup xampp folder and past in your new xampp"

C:\xampp\mysql\data

Comment: thank you Sapnesh Naik and Shital Marakana for the help, but i get this error now: localhost wont autorize access

Comment: here is the error:
Objet non trouvé!

L'URL demandée n'a pas pu être trouvée sur ce serveur. La référence sur la page citée semble être erronée ou perimée. Nous vous prions d'informer l'auteur de cette page de cette erreur.

Si vous pensez qu'il s'agit d'une erreur du serveur, veuillez contacter le webmestre.

Error 404

localhost
Apache/2.4.17 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2d PHP/5.6.15

Comment: the url of my website is localhost/mywebsite when i try to get in, it gives me the wordpress install page, so i choose the language, the name of the website, the admin login, password and email adresse, and then nothing error